# Why won't MP4 video work with HTML5 <video> tag on Firefox

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Because I dislike Youtube and Vimeo is too expensive, I chose to upload my videos directly to the server at my web host and embed the videos on my site using the HTML5  tag (see photos for the code). The videos play fine on all browsers except for Firefox and I can't figure out why. https://memoriaelinguagrumentina.org/english/saponareseCuisine.html

I've seen several other posts on here asking about very similar problems; however, nearly all are at least 8 years old. I've gone through them as part of my troubleshooting process, but without any luck.

1. I've seen it recommended here to use multiple video formats (.mp4 AND .ogv) because there is no universal format supported by all browsers. Firefox did not always support mp4, but I believe it does now. So I don't believe this is the root of the problem.
2. I checked with my web host to see if they have the correct MIME types (see photo).
3. I cleared the cache on my browser, set the privacy settings to normal, and checked hardware acceleration.

What am I missing?

*note: To save disk space, I'd like to not have to upload duplicate videos in different video formats to the server, ideally. Since Firefox now claims to support mp4, I was hoping to get away with using only mp4.

[image: This is how it displays on Firefox]
[image: Here's the code]
[image: Supported MIME types]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support all video files. They generally support **`MP3`**, **`WebM`**, **`Ogg`**, and **`Wave`** containers, and if you are using an **`MP4`** container then it usually depends on the platform decoders for **`AAC`** and **`H.264`** audio and video streams. The video encoder format that you are using isn't supported by firefox. You should use supported encoders for your video.
[image: firefox video & audio tips]

You can find more information here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the encoder mattered.

Answer (score 2):

Your MP4 videos are using **H.265** video codec. 
You need to have them **encoded as H.264** to work in most browsers.
**Solution:** This means you must re-save your videos as a new format.

The problem is not just Firefox, even Windows Chrome does not play H.265 encoded video.

**Things to fix:**

- Re-encode as **H.264** (use High or Main **profile** for better compression-vs-quality output).
- Re-size your videos (when doing re-encode). 720p should be okay for demos/intros. 
  You don't need a large **3840 x 2160** pixels video showing inside a small **672 x 398** pixels box.
- Your file size is not good. **286** mb is too much data loading for just a mere 6 minute video.

Comment: This was important for me to learn, thanks.